Routing issue in nested Child
I have two component in one component.ts on the click of button i call openClientCallLogs function but routing does not work the url will create but they did'nt go to another component
on the click of button
openClientCallLogs(client: Client): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/index/client/clients-detail', client.id ,'call-logs']);
  }

Routing of module
export const clientsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'client',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'clients-detail',
        component: ClientDetailsComponent,
        children: [
          { 
            path: ':id/call-logs',
            component: ClientCallLogsComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
];

This is following my App.routing module
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./pages/pages.module').then((m) => m.PagesModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'index',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./pages/clients/clients.module').then((m) => m.ClientsModule),
      },


please share a stackblitz with the minimal code and issue replicated

The project component has a lot of dependencies

just need routes with blank components, where the issue happens

does your ClientDetailsComponent contain a router outlet?

@SamScholefield no if i add router outlet in detail they did'nt go to another page they display that page on exixting one

You need to create a component, that will be a container to render either ClientDetailsComponent or ClientCallLogsComponent, this will solve your problem.
Let's say the component is called ClientDetailComponent.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  standalone: true,
  template: `<router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class ClientDetailComponent {
}

Then add this wrapper component, in the routing like so.
  export const clientsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'client',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'clients-detail', 
          component: ClientDetailComponent,
          children: [
            {
              path:'',
              component: ClientDetailsComponent,
            },
            { 
              path: ':id/call-logs',
              component: ClientCallLogsComponent
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
  ];


is it not possible if they are the childrean of clients-detail

@gouravkumar updated the same!

yeahh Working now

I think the problem you have is that you don't want to have ClientDetailsComponent as a parent and only want to use ClientCallLogsComponent. To achieve this, you can change your clientsRoutes like this.
  export const clientsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'client',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'clients-detail',
          children: [
            {
              path:'',
              component: ClientDetailsComponent,
            },
            { 
              path: ':id/call-logs',
              component: ClientCallLogsComponent
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
  ];


i add but nothing happn

When you inspect your page, which component is now in the DOM or is there no component now in the DOM?

ClientDetailsComponent

Okay, so if you navigate to the new page and it shows you the correct path, but there is still the old component ClientDetailsComponent in the DOM, it is usually just one of these two problems. 1. Your component ClientCallLogsComponent has some issues, you can check your console logs and also try to clean the component and test again. 2. There is still a ClientDetailsComponent in your routing above your ClientCallLogsComponent. Please check again to make sure that the ClientDetailsComponent is only once in your routing file.
